# Using Jekyll, show latest post on front page and pagination

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I only want to show the latest post on the homepage on my Jekyll blog and I am using this neat hack to do that: https://gist.github.com/nimbupani/1421828

But I also want to show the "next post" below this latest post content on homepage.

How can I achieve that? If it helps I am using this code to show "next post" and "previous post" links on the post pages https://gist.github.com/sushimashi/7237224

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the [Jekyll Paginator](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/)?

In your `_config.yml' add this:

```
paginate: 1
```

Then use `paginator.previous_page` and `paginator.next_page` to generate links to the next/previous post.

That example you linked to only displays the first post on the home page. Presumably you'd then have an archive page that lists all the other posts. It's not designed for this one-post-per-page approach that you're taking here.

Comment: Thanks I am sort of trying to create a blogazine framework on top of jekyll with one post per page and homepage being the latest post. Below the post, the option to navigate to previous or next post. So are you saying one-post-per-page approach that I am trying is not possible in jekyll?

Comment: @Sushi No, it's absolutely possible, just use the paginator and not the approach you were taking. From here, I recommend you read through the documentation that I linked to, and if you have any more questions post them here on SO.